# How to write 2 lists to a text file?

Tags: r

I have 2 lists `res1` and `res2` that I want to write to a text file .

```
> res1
$`15`
       a
g 100

$`10`
       a
g 112

$`12`
       a
g 70

$`30`
       a
g 80
class(res1)
[1] "list"
str(res)
List of 12
$ 1 : num [1, 1] 100
..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
.. ..$ : chr "g"
.. ..$ : chr "a"
```

I tried this:`write.matrix(res1,file="myfile.txt",sep="")`
But I checked the output and it is like this:

```
  100
  112
  70
  80
```

my desired output:

```
  number  value
  15      100
  10      112
  12      70
  30      80
```

Comment: How about you share `dput(res1)` in your question.

Comment: Flatten each list and then use `cbind()` to join them together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (for two lists now):

```
# an example of a list:

lista <- vector("list", 4)
names(lista) <- c(1, 3, 5, 7)
lista[[1]] <- 30
lista[[2]] <- 50
lista[[3]] <- 20
lista[[4]] <- 33

lista2 <- vector("list", 4)
names(lista2) <- c(1, 3, 5, 7)
lista2[[1]] <- 33
lista2[[2]] <- 5
lista2[[3]] <- 290
lista2[[4]] <- 332

# how to deal with the problem:

macierz <- as.matrix(lista)
macierz <- cbind(as.numeric(rownames(macierz)), macierz)

macierz2 <- as.matrix(lista2)

kolejnosc <- match(rownames(macierz), rownames(macierz2))
cbind(macierz, macierz2[kolejnosc, ]) -> result
colnames(result) <- c("number", "value1", "value2")

write.table(result, "./lista.txt", 
            row.names=FALSE, col.names=TRUE)
```

Comment: I've edited my answer in order to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
# sample input
lb <- lapply(1:4, function(x) round(runif(1)*100))
lc <- lapply(1:4, function(x) round(runif(1)*100))

# assuming both lists have the same name
names(lb) <-names(lc) <- c(1:4)

# writing to a file
write.table(x = data.table(name=names(lb), 
                           vb=as.vector(sapply(lb, `[`)),
                           vc=as.vector(sapply(lc, `[`))),
            file = './justCreated.txt',
            row.names = F, col.names = T, quote = F)
```